# Unable to read variable annotations from Scala macro

Tags: scala, reflection, macros, annotations

I'm trying to write a macro in Scala, which reads variables with a certain annotations to manipulate them, but it seems *annotations* property of variable symbols always return an empty list.

Annotation signature:

```
class Inject extends StaticAnnotation
```

Annotation usage:

```
object App {
  @Inject
  var service: HttpService = _
}
```

Macro definition (blackbox) :

```
def inject[T <: Config](c: Context)(target: c.Expr[T])(implicit tag: c.WeakTypeTag[T]): c.Expr[ModuleProxy] = {
  import c.universe._

  val fields = tag.tpe.members collect { case s: TermSymbol => s}

  // Always empty.
  fields foreach { s => println(s"$s : ${s.annotations}") }
}
```

Is there something I should look into? Any kind of suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a full example at, say, github?

Comment: @EugeneBurmako Sure, it's already at GH, but I removed the relevant part for it was not working. I'll include it again with comments, and post the link here this weekend. Thanks!

Comment: I just readded the part which causes the problem with a comment : 

* https://github.com/greencatsoft/scalajs-angular/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/greencatsoft/angularjs/internal/ServiceProxy.scala#L29

It's supposed to read list of variables with @inject annotation from a given type, but it does not work as expected.

If you need a working example which can reproduce the issue, you can run 'sbt localPublish' on the above project, and try to build the following project :

* https://github.com/greencatsoft/scalajs-angular-todomvc

Thanks!

Comment: Does my answer work for you?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't annotate your annotation with one of `scala.annotation.meta` annotations, the annotation will land on underlying fields of vals/vars. To get hold of those, do `val fields = tag.tpe.decls.collect{ case s: TermSymbol if !s.isMethod => s }`, and then it should be okay.